# Wrap figure in theorem-environment

Tags: lists, indentation, picins

I'd like to wrap a figure around a theorem-environment but when I use the wrapfig or \parpic environment the text overlaps the figure. Plain text automatically wraps around a \parpic figure but the itemize/enumerate environment doesn't. Therefore I came up with a work-around:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,picins}%+any other needed packages..
\newcommand{\items}{\hspace{1.25em} \textbullet \hspace{0.55em}} %tried to replicate the alignment of the itemize environment.

\begin{document}
\parpic[r]{
\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{image.jpg}
}
\items this long text would have overlapped the picture if it would have been an 'itemize' environment
\items and so on..
\end{document}
```

This works but now I'd like to indent each new line after the bullet so it is right below the upper one (like the itemize environment). sth like `\items{long text}`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `mdwlist` package to do this.

[image: It's going to look this]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry} % for the sake of presentation

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{picins}
\usepackage{mdwlist}

\begin{document}

\noindent
Once upon a time, there was an image... and an enumeration...

\begin{enumerate}
\parpic[r]{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{image.jpg}}
\item it had line after line but didn't touch the image...
\item it had line after line but didn't touch the image...
\item it had line after line but didn't touch the image...
\item it had line after line but didn't touch the image...
\suspend{enumerate}
\resume{enumerate}
\item ...and filled the remaining space
\end{enumerate}

\newpage
\noindent
It could have been reset before the third line, like this:

\begin{enumerate}
\parpic[r]{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{image.jpg}}
\item it had line after line but didn't touch the image...
\item it had line after line but didn't touch the image...
\suspend{enumerate}
\resume{enumerate}
\item it had line after line but didn't touch the image...
\item it had line after line but didn't touch the image...
\item ...and filled the remaining space
\end{enumerate}

\noindent
But it wasn't.

\noindent
The End!

\end{document}
```

UPDATE: you may also want to consider using a two-column environment (`paracol` for example), or `minipage`s.