# Aligning \item dots partially in minipage

Tags: graphics, horizontal-alignment, itemize

[image: Item allignment]

As you can see on my added image, I have added the first `\item` in a `minipage` together with a figure which results in the "item dot" is a little more centred then the two other "item dots".
I have tried putting all three \items on the same `minipage` but the page is not big enough which results in the text covering the page number.
I have also tried playing with `\usepackage{wrapfig}` with no luck.

Does anyone have any ideas ?

Comment: Issue a `\noindent` before you start the `minipage`.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Werner has the answer. :) Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/127465/wrap-figure-in-theorem-environment/137144#137144

Answer (score 3):

Unless altered, paragraph elements are issued with an indent, which is the case here. Issue a `\noindent` before you start the `minipage`, which should align the items.

The following replicates the behaviour:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
  \item An item
\end{itemize}

\begin{minipage}{.65\linewidth}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item Another item
  \end{itemize}
\end{minipage}

\bigskip

\noindent
\begin{minipage}{.65\linewidth}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item Another item
  \end{itemize}
\end{minipage}

\begin{itemize}
  \item An item
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```